# JTable does not fill JScrollPane which is added to JPanel using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a `JPanel` with `GridBagLayout`. The panel contains 2 rows, first row has a JLabel and second row has a `JScrollPane` with `JTable` inside. The table does not fill 100% of the scrollpane. Even I resize my frame, the scrollpane resizes but the table inside always has fixed width.

```
JTable table=new JTable(myModel);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); 
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(table);

JPanel panel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
// component add details skipped
```

And the following are the grid bag constraints applied to scroll pane while adding to panel.

```
GridBagConstraints gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx=0; // first column
gbc.gridy=1; // second row
gbc.gridwidth=1;
gbc.gridheight=1;
gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
gbc.weightx=1.0;
gbc.weighty=1.0;
```

What went wrong? Problem is with scroll pane or table?

Comment: Did you add the scrollpane to the panel ?

Comment: yes, and the panel has gridbaglayout

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Where is `panel.add(scroll)` ?

Comment: component add details skipped in the question. `panel.add(scroll, gbc);`

Comment: Why are you setting the autoResizeMode to OFF? Isn't it what prevents the table to auto-resize to the width of the scrollpane?

Comment: @JBNizet because Im setting column width later in my code. I removed that line and checked. Still problem exists.

Comment: Then post an SSCCE, so that we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for giving valuable suggestions. I found the exact solution for this problem. Size the table at its preferred size or view port size whichever is greater. Regardless of whatever layout manager you use it is working fine!

The solution is have table defined with `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()` method, as example given below:

```
JTable table=new JTable(myModel){
 public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
   return getPreferredSize().width < getParent().getWidth();
 }
};
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(table);
```

Comment: I had the problem of the JTable not being wide enough to fill the scrollpane when no rows were in it.  This made receiving DragNDrop msgs difficult.  
This fixed that perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

I think that only (notice rows never will be resized by using any of LayoutManager, only columns)

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 0;
```

GBC isn't proper LayoutManager for JComponents implements Scrollable, use BorderLayout(ev GridLayout) for these JComponents

for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JTableAndGBC {

    private String[] columnNames = {"Source", "Hit", "Last", "Ur_Diff"};
    private JTable table;
    private Object[][] data = {{"Swing Timer", 2.99, 5, 1.01},
        {"Swing Worker", 7.10, 5, 1.010}, {"TableModelListener", 25.05, 5, 1.01}};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    public JTableAndGBC() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        table = new JTable(model);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        panel.add(table, gbc);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JTableAndGBC();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT 1

- `JTable`, `JScollPane`, `JComboBox` can't returns reasonable `PreferredSize`, see my code in the edit, then wokrs for all `LayoutManagers`,
- notice carefully with `table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());`, I'd suggest to test if Dimension overload desired coordinates or screen resolution or not overload :-),
- otherwise to shrink with `new Dimension(int, int)` instead of `table.getPreferredSize()`

.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JTableAndGBC {

    private String[] columnNames = {"Source", "Hit", "Last", "Ur_Diff"};
    private JTable table;
    private Object[][] data = {{"Swing Timer", 2.99, 5, 1.01},
        {"Swing Worker", 7.10, 5, 1.010}, {"TableModelListener", 25.05, 5, 1.01}};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    public JTableAndGBC() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        table = new JTable(model);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        panel.add(pane, gbc);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JTableAndGBC();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT 2

I'm strongly to suggest to use BorderLayout, GridLayout

[image]

.

[image]

instead of GBC (`JTable`, `JScollPane`, `JComboBox` can't returns reasonable `PreferredSize`, required to override GBC, brrrr, not why bothering)

[image] . [image]

code for BorderLayout

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class JTableAndGBC {

    private String[] columnNames = {"Source", "Hit", "Last", "Ur_Diff"};
    private JTable table;
    private Object[][] data = {{"Swing Timer", 2.99, 5, 1.01},
        {"Swing Worker", 7.10, 5, 1.010}, {"TableModelListener", 25.05, 5, 1.01}};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    public JTableAndGBC() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()/*(new GridBagLayout()*/);
        table = new JTable(model);
        //GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        //gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        //gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table, 
                ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        /*TableColumn firstColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        firstColumn.setMinWidth(150);
        firstColumn.setMaxWidth(200);
        TableColumn secondColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        secondColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        secondColumn.setMaxWidth(250);
        TableColumn thirdColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        thirdColumn.setMinWidth(50);
        thirdColumn.setMaxWidth(100);   */     
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        panel.add(pane/*, gbc*/);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JTableAndGBC();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you say problem with scroll pane? because in my code jscrollpane perfectly resizes both horizontally and vertically. but the jtable (which is inside jscrollpane) does not.

Comment: yes is possible, without any issue, this is basic knowledge about how to LayouotManagers works

Comment: found solution that the table should set its preferred size or view port size which ever is greater, so that at any circumstances it fill the full width of the scroll pane.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

line. It causes the fixed table size.

Comment: thats actually not solving the issue.